# Angular 6 :material checkbox checked all checkbox in loop

Tags: angular6

In loop

```
  <li *ngFor="let item of verticalList;let i=index;">
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked" name="i">Checked</mat-checkbox>
</li>
```

I want to give each checkbox a different checked value. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is verticalList type, but id you use a list of object you could do something like this:

```
verticalList = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'foo1',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'foo2',
    checked: false
  }
]

<li *ngFor="let item of verticalList;let i=index;">
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.checked" name="i">Checked {{ item.name }}</mat-checkbox>
</li>
```